# Finding percentage with only the mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics

All sections of an Introduction to Criminology courseat a large university were given the same finalexam. Test scores were distributed normally with a mean of 68and a standard deviation of6.  What percentage of students scored between 60 and 69 (a grade of C) and what percentage scored between 70 and 79 (a grade of B)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.se! It seems you have just posted a problem you want solved.  This site is not a problem solving service.  Be specific as to what you have tried and what you are unsure of.

Answer (score 1):

Only hints to guide you.

a) Do you know how to find the $z$-scores correponding to each of those marks?

b) Using the $z$-scores, do you know how to determine the area under the normal curve between two given $z$-values? This may involve using either tables or a special calculator (they're available on the web).

c) Areas under the normal curve correspond to proportions (lying between $0$ and $1$), so you should know how to convert those to percentages.

Comment: If you have access to software or a statistical calculator you can avoid 'standardizing' to get z-scores: In R statistical software,  `diff(pnorm(c(60,69), 68, 6))` returns 0.4749726 and
`diff(pnorm(c(70,79), 68, 6))` returns 0.3360648. So, roughly $1/2$ C's and $1/3$ B's.